# Can "sure" be used as a complete answer here?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, idiomatic-language

Guy: You should come.

Another guy: Sure.

Can "sure" be used as a complete answer here, to mean "yeah, I'd like that"?

Comment: "Sure" can be used to imply various affirmative answers such as _Yes, I will - Yes, you may_ etc.

Comment: In your example, the answer does NOT make it clear whether the respondent intends to come or is merely being evasive. If you are asking whether a single word response is sufficient to answer a question, the answer is YES, depending on the response.

Comment: The asker will probably take it as "Sure, I will come" which may or may not be the intended meaning.  The responder may just be saying "You're right, I should come" which doesn't indicate they will.